# How to update field value to auto-increment field value?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I have one table orders with two fields id(auto_increment) & order_id.
I want to update order_id with the value of id field means if id = 1 then order_id = 1, if id = 2 then order_id = 2 so on.....

**How can i do that with MySQL query or php script?**

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update your_table
set order_id = id
where order_id is null 
or order_id = 0
or order_id = ''
```

Comment: Sure, but in SQL is way faster.

Comment: I have more then 20,000 records, so it's your query faster then phpscript.

Comment: Doing something directly in the DB is always faster.